# Active Case ContactId (Apex)

Tags: apex, case

I need access to the current active case ID so I can pass it to my embedded react app (lightning container).  By "current" active case I mean the case that is currently clicked and open on salesforce. I am aware that there can be multiple open cases, but I need the case that the agent has click on and is open on the UI.

See screenshot for more clarity - I want the information on the right side so I can pass it to our embedded app.
[image: active case example]

This works in getting all contact ids from the cases - but I just need the active one.  Thanks.

```
global static Case[] getContactsTesting(String key) {
    String searchKey = '%' + key + '%';
    return [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM Case
     
               LIMIT 20];
}
```

Comment: Users can have more than one case open. Please [edit] your post to provide more context (for example, if you're working in a Service Console application) and detail about your objectives.

Comment: Thanks! Editted.

Comment: It's record page here you have access to recordId in both Aura and LWC components.

Comment: Thanks!! Once I get the recordId - how do I query it to get access to the contactId?